# getting haskellmode-vim to work with a cabal project

Tags: cabal, haskell-mode

When I build a cabal project in vim, using

```
:set makeprg=cabal\ build
:make
```

[haskellmode-vim](https://github.com/lukerandall/haskellmode-vim) doesn't seem to find the type information. Doing `_t` when the cursor is on `foo` gives me "foo type not known".

How can I get haskellmode-vim to obtain the type information from a cabal build?

Answer (score 5):

Doing `:GHCReload` allows me to use `_t` and `_T`.